# Is it possible to construct a rectangular equivalent of the identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question

Usually the identity matrix is a square matrix but is it possible to construct a rectangular equivalent of the identity matrix ?

Do we need to add some additional condition for the construction of such mathematical object ?

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Comment: What properties do you want from this generalized identity matrix?

Comment: I am not even sure of that, it is actually just a simple curiosity. Can you recomend some interesting properties for me ?

Comment: It might be worth exploring the pseudo-inverse of a rectangular matrix. In particular, every matrix $A$ has a unique [Moore-Penrose inverse][1] $A^+$. If the matrix is square and invertible then its Moore-Penrose inverse is the standard inverse. Perhaps one could think of $A^+ A$ and $A A^+$ as generalizing the identity in some sense idk.